# check internet connection with phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am seeing a few different options to check internet connection with phonegap. There is `document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);` and there is also `navigator.network.connection.type`... but I am not sure which one is best practice. I would also like to be able to prevent the bad case where the phone is connected to a wifi network but has no internet connection.

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','#explanation-short', function(){
     if ( isPhoneGap() ) {
    if (checkConnection() == "none" ) {
        connectionStatus = 'offline'; 
    } else {
        connectionStatus = 'online';
    }
    function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
        //console.log('Connection : ' + Connection);
        //console.log('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
        return networkState;
    }
} else {
    connectionStatus = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
}
    console.log("connectionStatus : "+connectionStatus);
});
```

For example, this code works if the phone is connected to the wifi, but we are not sure the internet is actually available.

What are the best practices with phonegap 3.3+ and Jquery mobile 1.4 ?

Comment: Your really want to look into implementing a Reachability class, and use that in addition to the network and online/offline handling. btw, not sure if your checkConnection function is called in your sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event,

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
```

is only fired when your app is already is loaded and regains a connection. This is not fired on start of the application.

Therefore, you have to use the `checkConnection()` method on start of your application and then if you need to check later while the app is running, you use the event listener.

Comment: why can't I use checkConnection() anywhere anytime ?

Comment: You can. Using the event listener will catch it right when it happens, if you choose to call the other method, then it will only catch it when you ask for it. My point was that you can't use the event listener on load.

Answer (score 4):

Inside device ready function , I use the following lines to check for internet connection

```
if(navigator.connection.type==0)
{
    alert('This application requires internet. Please connect to the internet.');

}
else if(navigator.connection.type=='none')
{
    alert('This application requires internet. Please connect to the internet.');

}
else
{
    //Hurray I'm online
}
```

Currently this is serving me quite well. But I still don't have that way to detect **connected wifi,but no internet**.I would also like to know how to detect that.

Comment: It is not working, tried disconnecting Wifi but still shows online.

Answer (score 0):

In Phonegap there are two event listeners 'online' & 'offline'. use them for fast response.Please check Example :

---

```
var internet;
document.addEventListener('online',online,false);
document.addEventListener('offline',offline,false);


function online(){

  internet=true;
}

function offline(){
 internet=false;
}

if(internet){

// internet is connected

}else{

// internet is not connected
}
```

---

for more details please visit http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html